# are php references a good idea when handling large or many arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, reference

Finally I have something to ask the community

My case: I have some box-like objects with internal arrays, I wish to manipulate these arrays inside methods, but a donating box must result empty after a merging operation. I'm currently using references so as to not copy large arrays, but I just recently came across a great post: [do not use php references](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/125-Do-not-use-PHP-references.html).

```
class Box implements MadeUpArrayLikeInterfaces {
  protected $v = array();
  ...
  public function __clone() {
    foreach ($this->v as &$v) {// correct the mess left behind the cloning process?
      if (is_object($v)) $v = clone $v;// perhaps I shouldn't deep clone anything?
    }
  }
  public function merge() {
    $boxes = func_get_args();// variable argument list
    arary_unshift($boxes,$this->v);
    array_walk(array($this,'walkUnwrap'),$boxes);// prepare input, allow only arrays
    $this->v = call_user_func('array_merge',array_filter($boxes));// merge
  }
  public function import(self $box) {// edited to make more sense
    $this->v = array_merge($this->v,$box->v);// do the merge
    $box->v  = array();
  }
  public function export() {
    $e = array();   // empty array that may be referenced
    $r =& $this->v; // avoid copying for return
    $this->v =& $e; // point to empty because assignment would erase $r as well
    return $r;      // return contents
  }
  private static function walkUnwrap(&$v) {// walks on argument list
    if ($v instanceof self && $v->v) {// if element is Box, export it
      $e = array();
      $o = $v;    // save reference to the Box
      $v =& $v->v;// pass the data
      $o->v =& $e;// this box should now be empty
    } elseif (!is_array($v)) $v = null;// if it's anything but array get rid of it
  }
}
```

So now I'm wondering if my approach is actually correct. Are these operations "writes" as stipulated in the post and therefore it's better to use references? are these copy-values?

Thank you all

edited: indeed I have been careless, the import function is much simpler, and I have a better function that also use references that could be useful in showing what this is about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, if you assign `$box->v  =& $e;` then if you change `$box->v` anywhere afterwards to `array('foo', 'bar')` the variable `$e` changes also to this value. So next time you assign `$e` in your class method `import()` the property `v` of your arg `$box` will afterwards be `array('foo', 'bar')` too.

If you can ensure that `$box->v` never gets changed anywhere after `$box->v  =& $e;` line of code then it works. But seems a bit lazy and risky to me.

Since PHP5 mostly everything is treated as reference. That means that more or less every complex type of a variable (`objects`) only gets passed by reference (for function / method calls).

To create a new instance with same content - a copy - of a "complex" variable use the language construct [`clone`](http://php.net/manual/de/language.oop5.cloning.php).

But not every object is cloneable. You can refuse cloning for objects of your own class with the magic method [`__clone()`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/language.oop5.cloning.php#object.clone).

A singleton class for example is often not cloneable (which makes sense). So a singleton can only be passed by reference cause it can only exist once.

Comment: the reason I use `$box->v =& $e;` is because I want the donator object to have an array (albeit, an empty one). I suppose that since this empty array is generated on each method call, every object would be garanteed to have a prop `v = array()` regardless of whether they are donating or receiving. Am I wrong? :/
...I'm not sure of what you're presuming here? I'll test what you've written and get back to you in a moment

Comment: You are right, I was lazy and careless in the import function, that is fixed. I added `clone` magic for completeness but I think I'll remove it altogether and allow only extending classes to implement it. `->merge` uses the same `->export` functionality to cleanup the arguments so that it's all arrays. That being said, if I have full control over `$this->v`, would this code be using references correctly? (PS:sorry for double comment, I can't edit the earlier one)